# argument must be this, but this isn't right?

Tags: python, pygame, typeerror

OK, so I'm working with pygame and I'm trying to make a system where when the character hits the side of the screen area, some large text appears and says "You Crashed". but when I try the code and crash into the wall, nothing happens and I get an error in the shell

```
error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\pygame test.py", line 88, in <module>
    game_loop()
  File "D:\pygame test.py", line 84, in game_loop
    crash()
  File "D:\pygame test.py", line 44, in crash
    message_display('You Crashed')
  File "D:\pygame test.py", line 34, in message_display
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurface)
TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not pygame.Rect.
```

do you guys know what is going on and how I could fix this issue?
code:

```
def message_display (text):
    LargeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 115)
    TextRect = text_objects(text, LargeText)
    TextSurface = text_objects(text, LargeText)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width/2), (display_height/2))
    pygame.display.flip()
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurface)
```

much appreciated.

Comment: what is `text_objects` function? The error seems to imply that it returns a `pygame.rect` when blit requires a `pygame.Surface`

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what `text_objects` is to be honest with you. but I think it may just be trying to make things easier or something like that

Answer (score 0):

Guessing that you're working through the example on [this site](https://pythonprogramming.net/displaying-text-pygame-screen/).

So your `text_objects` function looks like:

```
def text_objects(text, font):
    textSurface = font.render(text, True, black)
    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()
```

Then you need to change your `message_display` function to handle both returns from `text_objects()`:

```
def message_display (text):
    LargeText = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 115)
    TextSurface, TextRect = text_objects(text, LargeText)
    TextRect.center = ((display_width/2), (display_height/2))
    gameDisplay.blit(TextSurface)
    # this next line should probably only be called in your main loop
    pygame.display.flip()
```